# Change in output depending on mirt version

Tags: r

I have a matrix which I'm trying to run through the `mirt` function of the `mirt` package:

```
resp.freq <- data.frame(matrix(c(11, 46, 12, 31, 13, 8, 21, 20, 22, 68, 23, 12,
                                 31,  1, 32, 12, 33, 11), nrow = 9, ncol = 2,
                               byrow = T))
dados3 <- matrix(rep(resp.freq$X1, resp.freq$X2), ncol = 1)
dados3 <- data.frame(cbind(as.numeric(substr(dados3, 1, 1)),
                           as.numeric(substr(dados3, 2, 2))))

require(mirt)
m1 <- mirt(dados3, 1, D = 1, SE = TRUE)
coef(m1)
```

I used to run this through **mirt 0.5.0** and would get the following end results:

```
$X1
        a1    d1     d2
pars 1.913 0.633 -3.152
SE   0.228 0.181  0.322

$X2
        a1    d1     d2
pars 1.659 1.121 -2.488
SE   0.200 0.190  0.261
```

However, my workstation has been updated and on **mirt 1.2.1** and now I get the following output upon running `m1 <- mirt(...`:

```
Iteration: 1000, Log-Lik: -387.670, Max-Change: 0.00007
EM iterations terminated after 1000 iterations.


Calculating information matrix...
Warning message:
In loadESTIMATEinfo(info = info, ESTIMATE = ESTIMATE, constrain = constrain) :
  Negative SEs set to NaN.
```

And `coef(m1)` gives me:

```
$X1
            a1    d1     d2
par     11.515 2.732 -13.98
CI_2.5     NaN 0.685    NaN
CI_97.5    NaN 4.778    NaN

$X2
           a1    d1     d2
par     1.099 0.903 -2.139
CI_2.5  0.712 0.561 -2.611
CI_97.5 1.485 1.245 -1.668

$GroupPars
        MEAN_1 COV_11
par          0      1
CI_2.5      NA     NA
CI_97.5     NA     NA
```

I've read the [changelog](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mirt/NEWS), but couldn't find a reason for the behavior change. I've tried desperately changing the parameters of `mirt()`, but couldn't reach even a similar level of convergence. What gives?

Comment: BTW, should this be posted here or on Cross Validated?

Comment: Preferably neither, use the mirt-package forum instead if it's only package related. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview

Comment: @philchalmers, actually, it's also a bit statistics-related, since the issue also made me wonder if I was doing something I shouldn't.